# SQL Server Profiler Trace: finding Stored Procedures that are slow(est) and resource-consuming

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am running a few traces capturing specifically these 2 events:

```
RPC:Completed
SP:StmtCompleted
```

But what concerns me is that when I later analyze the trace data (querying table, aggregating, etc..), is that I may not be summarizing correct metrics. Because for example, for ONE RECORD for `RPC:Completed` event there may be 3 records for `SP:StmtCompleted` event, right?

So for example `DURATION` value may be recorded four times in such case for same SP EXEC but in my analysis I will be summarizing all four? Which seems incorrect.  Because for one `EXEC <SPname> (RPC:Completed)` the trace may contain many rows related to the same occurrence of EXEC this SP if there is a certain number of SQL Statements executed in it.

Should I then NOT be using the `SP:StmtCompleted` event, not to mess up my analysis/metrics of performance?

Answer (score 0):

RPC:Completed encompasses SP:StmtCompleted.  You need to use one or the other.